# While creating charts in hidden Word2010, Excel opens. How to disable this? 

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word

Question in short :

this line:

```
doc.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject("Excel.Chart.8"); // doc is a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document object
```

opens Excel. How to disable this?

---

more details:

I am trying to create docx documents from a template with scripting Word2010 in c#. 
I open a document this way:

```
Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Open(@"xxxx.docx",Visible:false);
```

During the script, Word2010 does not appear, but Excel2010 does, when I create a chart inside the word document ("Excel.Chart.8")

I see the whole chart scripting process on my monitor, which is not what I want.

Is there any way to hide Excel2010 (Chart Tools) during the process?

edit: An example of creating an excel chart:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Open(@"xxxx.docx",Visible:false);
string classtype = "Excel.Chart.8";
Bookmark shapeBookMark = doc.Bookmarks.get_Item("mybookmark");
Word.InlineShape wrdInlineShape = doc.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(classtype, Range: shapeBookMark.Range);
if (wrdInlineShape.OLEFormat.ProgID == classtype)
      {
         object verb = Word.WdOLEVerb.wdOLEVerbHide;
         wrdInlineShape.OLEFormat.DoVerb(ref verb);
         Excel.Workbook obook = (Excel.Workbook)wrdInlineShape.OLEFormat.Object;
         Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)obook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
         //then the access of a cell goes like this:
         ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[1, 1]).Value = "data";
      }
```

Notice that Visible:false parameter must be used, because otherwise both excel and word will appear on a **long scripting process**. On a short one, it will not appear, but I need to do long scripting processes (creating, filling and formatting 16 charts/docx)

Comment: Can you post an example of creating the chart through code?

Comment: I added code to your example to open a new word doc and save it, but excel never showed up on my machine and the file saved correctly.

Comment: Did you use Visible:false parameter on document open? I want nothing to be shown at all while scripting.

Comment: If you do not use the parameter, then nothing will be shown on short docx files, because the script is finished before word2010 could open. On long docx files however after a time both word and excel will appear.

Comment: Try starting Excel, invisible, before you fire off the rest of the process?

Comment: I tried. Both with Process.Start using ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden , and setting the Visible property of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application to false (even created an empty workbook). But when the script reaches the AddOLEObject method, Excel becomes visible, no matter what I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recreate this on my machine, although I'm using Office 2007 rather than 2010. The only semi-solution I've managed to find so far is to get the active instance of Excel and switch it to invisible. Excel will flash up for a second and then disappear, but at least it will not remain visible while you perform your scripting/charting.

So inserting this into your code:

```
Word.InlineShape wrdInlineShape = doc.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(classtype, Range: shapeBookMark.Range);
Excel.Application xlApp = (Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
xlApp.Visible = false;

if (wrdInlineShape.OLEFormat.ProgID == classtype)
{
    // etc...
```